# The issue with the Fingerprint unlocking

Tags: huawei

I've got this Android device I bought recently. It is Huawei Y9 Prime. But I discovered yesterday there is an issue with the fingerprint ID. The lock can be unlocked by anyone!!! the device unlocks for all the fingerprints of all the people. So what should I do now? Is this a common error?

Comment: Can you [edit](https://android.stackexchange.com/posts/215474/edit) your post with the version of software (in settings)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you bought the [Huawei Y9 Prime](https://www.gsmarena.com/huawei_y9_prime_(2019)-9742.php), the phone is so new that its possible you have found a software bug/flaw or have a malfunctioning unit. Or it could be user error.

Based on your post history, the purchase is a few days old. I have a few options:

- Contact Huawei and notify them that there is a problem. They will probably recommend...
- Returning it to the seller for exchange with another unit. If you bought it in a physical store, you can show the clerk who can then verify that the fingerprint sensor is behaving incorrectly.
- If the second unit is bad, you can either return it for refund, or live with PIN lock with the hope that it is a software problem that can be patched.

Personally before returning/exchanging the unit, I would record a video setting up a freshly reset device, show the software version in the video, setup a fingerprint unlock and have a different user unlock it. It may just a manufacturing defect in the early production run or the software itself isn't the final consumer version. Either way, video proof can improve the odds of a fix if the problem is real.